# Data import (csv utf-8) into MySQL Benchmark 8.0 failed using Import Wizard showing syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I used Import Wizard to import a csv file (encoding UTF-8, I tried UTF-16, etc). However, I got such an error :

```
ERROR: Import data file: ("You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'élection`,`Région d'élection`,`Profession`,`Permanence`,`Entête 1 P`,`Entete'
 at line 1", 1064)
```

The special characters show correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL Workbench import wizard seems like it fails to escape apostrophes in column names. I tested this with MySQL Workbench 8.0.29 and I got a similar error as you did.

This is reported as a bug here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95700, but the bug is not yet fixed. They suggest a workaround of using JSON input files instead of CSV, but that doesn't help you if you must import CSV files.

Besides this bug, it is well known that the MySQL Workbench import wizard is [terrible for performance][4]. Even if you can get it to work by changing your column names, you won't be happy.

I recommend using the command-line tool [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html) or the equivalent SQL statement [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html). It's not a GUI, but it works with special column names, and it is orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familar with sql command line. I created a deatabase "matoya" and I would like to upload my csv file into this database. So I used: mysqlimport -u root -p --local matoya ~"C:/Users/Lli/OneDrive - STE D'EDITION PUBLIQUE - ACTEURS PU/Bureau/Matoya/Export Matoya/Matoya_D.csv" However, I got an error ERROR: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqlimport -u root -p --local matoya ~"C:/Users/Lli/OneDrive - STE D'EDITION PU' at line 1

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run mysqlimport inside a mysql client interface. You can't do that, you need to run it at a command prompt. On Windows this is `cmd.exe`. I suggest you find someone who can show you how to use command-line tools. It may be a learning curve because you have to learn about paths and things like that. It's too much for a Stack Overflow answer to cover.